# theme in windows phone(light or dark) using c#

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, colors

How do I know what the theme is selected in the settings (light or dark)?
I want to use a conditional statement such as

```
if (darkTheme) {..}
else {..}
```

Answer (score 6):

You want to find your response in the [official MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769545%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for Theme on Windows Phone.

In the part "Determining Theme Background" that indicate :

```
// Determine the visibility of the dark background.
Visibility darkBackgroundVisibility = 
    (Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"];

// Write the theme background value.
if (darkBackgroundVisibility == Visibility.Visible)
{
    textBlock1.Text = "background = dark";
}
else
{
    textBlock1.Text = "background = light";
}
```

Also, in this page, you've a part on the "theme accent color". To recover the two main colors defined by the user ( background and accent color).

Answer (score 3):

```
if( (Visibility)App.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] )
...
else
...
```

Comment: @YaroslavShabanov if this answered your question please check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I find the easiest approach to determine the theme is to use:

```
public bool darkTheme = ((Visibility)Application.Current.Resources["PhoneDarkThemeVisibility"] == Visibility.Visible);
```

is darkTheme is true then the selected theme is dark, and false for light.

Then in whatever procedure just use a simple `if` statement, such as:

```
if (darkTheme == true)
{
    //Do some stuff related to dark theme
}

else 
{
    //Do some stuff related to light theme
}
```

Comment: why not just do if(darkTheme) ?

Comment: True, either work, but one is the way pros do it and the other is the way Newbies do it lol.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell: It is to make code readable. Also while writing negative conditions, `== false` is more visible than the little `!`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Detecting the current theme. 

    private static Color lightThemeBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 255, 255); 
private static Color darkThemeBackground = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0); 
rivate static SolidColorBrush backgroundBrush; 

internal static AppTheme CurrentTheme 
    {
        get
        {
           if ( backgroundBrush == null )
               backgroundBrush = Application.Current.Resources["PhoneBackgroundBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;

           if (backgroundBrush.Color == lightThemeBackground)
                return AppTheme.Light;
           else if (backgroundBrush.Color == darkThemeBackground)
                return AppTheme.Dark;

           return AppTheme.Dark;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

BONUS: Install ThemeManager by Jeff Wilcox and switch between light and dark theme in your app with just one line of code!

http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2012/01/phonethememanager/